# Ruby, Unicorn, and environment variables

Tags: ruby, shell, nginx, environment, unicorn

While playing with Heroku, I found their approach of using environment variables for server-local configuration brilliant. Now, while setting up an application server of my own, I find myself wondering how hard that would be to replicate.

I'm deploying a sinatra application, riding Unicorn and Nginx. I know nginx doesn't like to play with the environment, so that one's out. I can probably put the vars somewhere in the unicorn config file, but since that's under version control with the rest of the app, it sort of defeats the purpose of having the configuration sit in the server environment. There is no reason not to keep my app-specific configuration files together with the rest of the app, as far as I'm concerned.

The third, and last (to my knowledge) option, is setting them in the spawning shell. That's where I got lost. I know that login and non-login shells use different rc files, and I'm not sure whether calling something with `sudo -u http stuff` is or not spawning a login shell. I did some homework, and asked google and man, but I'm still not entirely sure on how to approach it. Maybe I'm just being dumb... either way, I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on the whole shell environment deal.

Comment: The way I do that is to put these variables in the .bashrc file, this way, when I ssh to the server I will get these variables set directly without the need for a wrapper script, and they are secure because only the person that can log into the server that can access them. The wrapper script is useful if you want to deploy your app on multiple servers and have many variables to set.

Answer (score 7):

I think your third possibility is on the right track. What you're missing is the idea of a wrapper script, whose only function is to set the environment and then call the main program with whatever options are required.

To make a wrapper script that can function as a control script (if prodEnv use DB=ProdDB, etc), there is one more piece that simplifies this problem. Bash/ksh both support a feature called sourcing files. This an operation that the shell provides, to open a file and execute what is in the file, just as if it was in-lined in the main script. Like `#include` in C and other languages.

ksh and bash will automatically source `/etc/profile`, `/var/etc/profile.local` (sometimes), `$HOME/.profile`. There are other filenames that will also get picked up, but in this case, you'll need to make your own env file and the explicitly load it.

As we're talking about wrapper-scripts, and you want to manage how your environment gets set up, you'll want to do the sourcing inside the wrapper script.

How do you source an environment file?

```
envFile=/path/to/my/envFile  
. $envFile
```

where envFile will be filled with statements like

```
dbServer=DevDBServer
webServer=QAWebServer
....
```

you may discover that you need to export these variable for them to be visble

```
export dbServer webServer
```

An alternate assignment/export is supported

```
export dbServer=DevDBServer
export webServer=QAWebServer
```

Depending on how non-identical your different environments are, you can have your wrapper script figure out which environment file to load.

```
case $( /bin/hostame ) in
 prodServerName )
     envFile=/path/2/prod/envFile ;;
 QASeverName )
     envFile=/path/2/qa/envFile ;;
 devSeverName )
     envFile=/path/2/dev/envFile ;;
esac

. ${envFile}

#NOW call your program
myProgram -v -f inFile -o outFile ......
```

As you develop more and more scripts in your data processing environment, you can alway `source` your envFile at the top. When you eventually change the physical location of a server (or it's name), then  you have only one place that you need to make the change.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

Also a couple of gems dealing with this. [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) that works both with or without heroku. Figaro uses a yaml file (in config and git ignored) to keep track of variables. Another option is [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) that reads variables from an `.env` file. And also [another article](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) with all them options.

Answer (score 0):

To spawn an interactive shell (a.k.a. login shell) you need to invoke sudo like this:

```
sudo -i -u <user> <command>
```

Also you may use -E to preserve the environment. This will allow some variables to be pased for your current environment to the command invoked with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by explicitly telling Unicorn to read a variables file as part of startup in its `init.d` script. First I created a file in a directory above the application root called `variables`. In this script I call `export` on all my environment variables, e.g. `export VAR=value`. Then I defined a variable `GET_VARS=source /path/to/variables` in the `/etc/init.d/unicorn` file. Finally, I modified the start option to read `su - $USER -c "$GET_VARS && $CMD"` where `$CMD` is the startup command and `$USER` is the app user. Thus, the variables defined in the file are exported into the shell of Unicorn's app user on startup. Note that I used an init.d script almost identical to the one from [this article](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/setting-up-your-production-server-with-nginx-and-unicorn).