# Tool to extract java stack traces from log files

Tags: java, exception, logging, stack-trace

Is there any tool that can extract a list of stack traces appearing in the log file and probably count unique ones?

*EDIT*: I would preffer something that is not GUI-based and be run on the background and give some kind of report back. I have quite many logs gathered from several environments and just would like to get quick overview.

Comment: Why do you have so many stack traces in your log? Are you logging exceptions left and right? Are you certain that is a good idea?

Comment: That's a log from a performance test and certain parts of the system fail under pressure. The thing I want to achieve is a simpe report on where and which exceptions happended during the run.

Comment: It may be one exception happened in 1 day or it may be 1000 exceptions happened in one minute. The amount of exceptions is not determined by the amount of logs.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. As long as you don't need it to monitor a production system...

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788252/how-can-i-capture-java-exceptions-including-the-stack-trace-from-a-log-file-us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come up with the following Groovy script. It is, of course, very much adjusted to my needs, but I hope it helps someone.

```
def traceMap = [:]

// Number of lines to keep in buffer
def BUFFER_SIZE = 100

// Pattern for stack trace line
def TRACE_LINE_PATTERN = '^[\\s\\t]+at .*$'

// Log line pattern between which we try to capture full trace
def LOG_LINE_PATTERN = '^([<#][^/]|\\d\\d).*$'

// List of patterns to replace in final captured stack trace line 
// (e.g. replace date and transaction information that may make similar traces to look as different)
def REPLACE_PATTERNS = [
  '^\\d+-\\d+\\@.*?tksId: [^\\]]+\\]',
  '^<\\w+ \\d+, \\d+ [^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <',
  '^####<[^>]+?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <[^>]*?> <',
  '<([\\w:]+)?TransaktionsID>[^<]+?</([\\w:]+)?TransaktionsID>',
  '<([\\w:]+)?TransaktionsTid>[^<]+?</([\\w:]+)?TransaktionsTid>'
]

new File('.').eachFile { File file ->
  if (file.name.contains('.log') || file.name.contains('.out')) {
    def bufferLines = []
    file.withReader { Reader reader ->
      while (reader.ready()) {      
        def String line = reader.readLine()
        if (line.matches(TRACE_LINE_PATTERN)) {
          def trace = []
          for(def i = bufferLines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!bufferLines[i].matches(LOG_LINE_PATTERN)) {
              trace.add(0, bufferLines[i])
            } else {
              trace.add(0, bufferLines[i])
              break
            }
          }
          trace.add(line)
          if (reader.ready()) {
            line = reader.readLine()
            while (!line.matches(LOG_LINE_PATTERN)) {
              trace.add(line)
              if (reader.ready()) {
                line = reader.readLine()
              } else {
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          def traceString = trace.join("\n")
          REPLACE_PATTERNS.each { pattern ->
            traceString = traceString.replaceAll(pattern, '')
          }
          if (traceMap.containsKey(traceString)) {
            traceMap.put(traceString, traceMap.get(traceString) + 1)
          } else {
            traceMap.put(traceString, 1)
          }
        }
        // Keep the buffer of last lines.
        bufferLines.add(line)
        if (bufferLines.size() > BUFFER_SIZE) {
          bufferLines.remove(0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

traceMap = traceMap.sort { it.value }

traceMap.reverseEach { trace, number ->
  println "-- Occured $number times -----------------------------------------"
  println trace
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is a quick-and-dirty grep expression... if you are using a logger such as log4j than the first line of the exception will generally contain `WARN` or `ERROR`, the next line will contain the Exception name, and optionally a message, and then the subsequent stack trace will begin with one of the following:

1. `"\tat"` (tab character + `at`)
2. `"Caused by: "`
3. `"\t... <some number> more"` (these are the lines that indicate the number of frames in the stack not shown in a "Caused by" exception)
4. An Exception name (and perhaps message) before the stack

We want to get all of the above lines, so the grep expression is:

```
grep -P "(WARN|ERROR|^\tat |Exception|^Caused by: |\t... \d+ more)"
```

It assumes an Exception class always contains the word `Exception` which may or may not be true, but this is quick-and-dirty after all.

Adjust as necessary for your specific case.

Comment: It matches all lines with WARN or ERROR even if they are not followed by stack trace...

Comment: Can we create a regex to match the entire exception instead of the exception lines? I would like to combine this with this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276741/using-grep-and-looking-for-unique-occurrences

Comment: @GarouDan Once you have extracted all the stack traces using this logic, you can post-process to achieve what you want. For example, if you replace all `\n\t` with `|` you'll get each exception on one line, then you can `sort` / `uniq` / whatever using line-based tools, then you can replace all `|` with `\n\t` again.

Answer (score 13):

You can write this yourself pretty easily. Here is the pattern:

1. Open file
2. Search for the string `"\n\tat "` (that's new line, tab, `at`, blank) This is a pretty uncommon string outside of stack traces.

Now all you need to do is find the first line that doesn't start with `\t` to find the end of the stack trace. You may want to skip 1-3 lines after that to catch chained exceptions.

Plus add a couple of lines (say 10 or 50) before the first line of the stack trace to get some context.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I had the same idea and that's what I would do eventually if I don't find anything that's already there :). I'm pretty sure this feature is present in some comercial log analyzers, but I hoped something like that existed also as a free tool or example script.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a tool in Python. It manages to split two stack traces even if they come right after each other in the log.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Extracts exceptions from log files.
#

import sys
import re
from collections import defaultdict

REGEX = re.compile("(^\tat |^Caused by: |^\t... \\d+ more)")
# Usually, all inner lines of a stack trace will be "at" or "Caused by" lines.
# With one exception: the line following a "nested exception is" line does not
# follow that convention. Due to that, this line is handled separately.
CONT = re.compile("; nested exception is: *$")

exceptions = defaultdict(int)

def registerException(exc):
  exceptions[exc] += 1

def processFile(fileName):
  with open(fileName, "r") as fh:
    currentMatch = None
    lastLine = None
    addNextLine = False
    for line in fh.readlines():
      if addNextLine and currentMatch != None:
        addNextLine = False
        currentMatch += line
        continue
      match = REGEX.search(line) != None
      if match and currentMatch != None:
        currentMatch += line
      elif match:
        currentMatch = lastLine + line
      else:
        if currentMatch != None:
          registerException(currentMatch)
        currentMatch = None
      lastLine = line
      addNextLine = CONT.search(line) != None
    # If last line in file was a stack trace
    if currentMatch != None:
      registerException(currentMatch)

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
  processFile(f)

for item in sorted(exceptions.items(), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True):
  print item[1], ":", item[0]
```

Comment: Your script is working great. However it would nicer to add the Date of the Exception.

Comment: @Mitchapp do you have an example log file with dates?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/).

Comment: I know of that tool and actually I use it as well:). But I would preffer something that is not GUI-based. We have quite many logs and opening each one of them in the GUI is, unfortunately, not an option.