# Redirect PrintStackTrace to my own function

Tags: java

So im developing a Stacktrace inerpreter, so i want to know is there any way to redirect ALL e.printStackTrace() calls to my printTrace()?

Comment: You can replace `System.err` with a `PrintStream` of your own choosing. But that gets *everything* sent to `System.err`.

Comment: Do you mean in `try-catch` blocks? or do you mean changing what `e.printStackTrace()` does?

Comment: Before you start, I suggest you to take a look to exceptions handling documentation (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/89/exceptions-and-exception-handling#t=20170116170539288246)

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace what `e.printStackTrace()` does for all exceptions. It's non-final, meaning it can be overridden on subclasses, but the default implementation is simply:

```
printStackTrace(System.err);
```

So the only thing that you can hope to hook into there is `System.err`.

You can replace `System.err` with a `PrintStream` of your own choosing.

```
System.setErr(somePrintStream);
```

But that gets *everything* sent to `System.err`. You'd either have to deal with everything, or somehow extract just the stack traces ([some ideas are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107700/tool-to-extract-java-stack-traces-from-log-files)).

You might be better off somehow replacing all of your `e.printStackTrace()` calls with invocations of your method (they are of dubious value, anyway).

I don't know how best to suggest you do this; but you could, for instance, ban invocations of `Throwable.printStackTrace()` via a compiler tool like [Google's errorprone](http://errorprone.info/).

You may also be able to find tooling to do replacements based upon errorprone's findings.

Comment: This is a good answer but I feel it doesn't exactly answer the question, but rather tells of a possible approach (imo different than what OP is talking about). Personally, I think that your second suggestion could use some elaboration, which would make this answer much much better (again, this is how I see it...)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for fun, nice, but if it's for something professional, you're basically reinventing something like Sentry, so you're better off just paying for an off-the-shelf tool.

Like Andy Turner suggests, you could replace `printStackTrace()`, but it's very messy, not not reliable. Languages like Javascript and Python make this pretty easy to do, but in Java, it's hard because it goes against the philosophy of object-oriented programming (and hits limitations of older implementations of Java). There's a tool called Powermock that can replace methods, though. Might want to give that a look.

Remember how I mentioned Sentry? It does this through a logging framework. `printStackTrack()` is considered sloppy, anyway, so people usually migrate to something like slf4j to do proper logging. Rather than printing the stack trace, they do `LOGGER.warn("Error communicating with client {}", ipAddr, e);`. On the other end of the logger is an appender that's configured to actually log different levels (error, warn, info, debug, trace) and different classes. The way Sentry does this is it attaches an appender. If you did the same, you'd have a hook to just get `e`.

One last thing: either way, you might want to look into the [uncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)). Unless you're catching all throwables, you might miss something interesting and never log it.