# Filter log files for specific stack traces

Tags: awk, sed, log4j

I am trying to fetch exceptions from the log files. Logs are created by log4j, so they start with line containing ERROR, INFO, WARNING keywords.

I want to filter only ERROR level exceptions and only if exception was thrown by specific classes (let's assume that they all have ExampleClass in their name).

If such exception exists in file, I would like to fetch first line (containing ERROR), next line containing Exception and all following lines with whole stack trace (including "Caused by..." line).
In one log file there can be many excptions that I would like to fetch.

I should probably use `sed` or `awk`, but I don't know how to:

1) find separate stacks

2) check if at least one line of stack points to ExampleClass.

`grep` solution like this one [Tool to extract java stack traces from log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107700/tool-to-extract-java-stack-traces-from-log-files) is not enough, because it can't provide described filtering.

Comment: It should help if you could provide a sample of input lines from the log file and the output you expect, as usual on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "ExampleClass" will be on the same line as ERROR and that the undesired log results are for INFO,DEBUG,FATAL,WARN and TRACE levels.  I hope the comments will help intuit changes that can be made to fine tune the results:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

#Only match lines containing "ERROR" at the beginning and "ExampleClass" somewhere else on the same line
/^ERROR/ && /ExampleClass/ {

    #prints the very first line
    print $0

    #read in next line and print only those NOT related to INFO,DEBUG,FATAL,WARN or TRACE
    while ((getline == 1) && ($1 !~ /INFO|DEBUG|FATAL|WARN|TRACE/)) 

        print $0
    
}
```

Save the above code in a text file and run the script with your log file as an argument like so:

```
./script.awk java_log
```